# Unable to use AccessibilityService and DispatchGesture

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-service

I decided to create an application that can automatically perform screen touches that I'm going to use it on different devices that need automation.

I heard about '''AccessibilityService''' that led me to using `Android.Graphics.Path`, `GestureDescription` and `AccessibilityService`. I wasn't able to find a way that I could communicate with `AccessibilityService` so I decided to create a class that inherits from `AccessibilityService` that led me to access to `DispatchGesture` function but it actually doesn't work when I use this function.

This is my code and my AndroidManifest file:

Code:

```
public class DispatchGController : AccessibilityService
{

    public override void OnAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent e)
    {

    }

    public override void OnInterrupt()
    {
    }

    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();
        Core.WLDel("Service Created!");
    }

    protected override void OnServiceConnected()
    {
        base.OnServiceConnected();

        this.SetServiceInfo(new AccessibilityServiceInfo() { EventTypes = EventTypes.AllMask, FeedbackType = Android.AccessibilityServices.FeedbackFlags.Spoken, NotificationTimeout = 100 });
    }

    protected override bool OnGesture(int gestureId)
    {
        Core.WLDel(gestureId.ToString());
        return base.OnGesture(gestureId);
    }

    public DispatchGController()
    {
        var res = DispatchGesture(Core.TouchGestures.CreateClick(new Core.ACPointF(10, 200)), Core.MainCallback, null);
    }
}

        public class TouchGestures
    {
        const int ClickDuration = 1;
        public static GestureDescription CreateClick(ACPointF Point)
        {
            Path clickPath = new Path();
            clickPath.MoveTo(Point.X, Point.Y);
            GestureDescription.StrokeDescription clickStroke = new GestureDescription.StrokeDescription(clickPath, 0, ClickDuration);
            GestureDescription.Builder builder = new GestureDescription.Builder();
            builder.AddStroke(clickStroke);
            return builder.Build();
        }
    }
```

And this is my Manifest File:
[Manifest](https://easyupload.io/15xma9)
Any recommendations over this?